# Issue with returning sum of indexes of sliced list using Indexslice / .loc on a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, pandas-loc

Have been struggling with this for some time. I have the following multi-indexed by column Dataframe:

```
startd = pd.to_datetime('2022-06-01').date()
endd = pd.to_datetime('2022-08-01').date()

SW_NWE = ('NWE','MED')

df_SW_NWE = df.loc[startd:endd, idx['Sweet',SW_NWE]].cumsum(axis=1).round()
```

Which gives me this result:

```
Category     Sweet                                                    
Destination    NWE                         MED                        
Week            W1     W2     W3     W4     W1      W2      W3      W4
2022-06-01     0.0    0.0    0.0   70.0   70.0    70.0    70.0    70.0
2022-07-01   142.0  142.0  779.0  779.0  945.0   945.0  1015.0  1015.0
2022-08-01   236.0  661.0  732.0  914.0  996.0  1044.0  1044.0  1096.0
```

But am actually looking to get the sum of NWE + MED columns by Week in one slice, which would look like this:

```
Category     Sweet                                                    
Destination    (NWE+MED)                                                
Week            W1     W2     W3     W4     
2022-06-01     70.0    70.0    70.0   140.0   
2022-07-01   1087.0  1087.0  1794.0  1794.0 
2022-08-01   1232.0  1705.0  1776.0  2010.0
```

Will be doing it for a larger list so slicing each country then adding them together would be a solution but also very cumbersome in terms of code. This is similar to an excel pivot table where you can select several different sub categories (like countries) and you could get the sums as values. (In my case the cumulative sums).

Comment: I think you can continue to sum both columns from your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `stack()` + (do something) + `unstack()` trick to sum the columns.

`stack()` lets you reshape the wide df into a long one so that you can `sum()` the data by week; this creates a Series. After it's done, convert it into a frame by calling `to_frame()` and call `unstack()` to reshape the long frame into a wide one.

```py
# input
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        ('Sweet', 'NWE', 'W1'): {'2022-06-01': 0.0, '2022-07-01': 142.0, '2022-08-01': 236.0}, 
        ('Sweet', 'NWE', 'W2'): {'2022-06-01': 0.0, '2022-07-01': 142.0, '2022-08-01': 661.0}, 
        ('Sweet', 'NWE', 'W3'): {'2022-06-01': 0.0, '2022-07-01': 779.0, '2022-08-01': 732.0}, 
        ('Sweet', 'NWE', 'W4'): {'2022-06-01': 70.0, '2022-07-01': 779.0, '2022-08-01': 914.0}, 
        ('Sweet', 'MED', 'W1'): {'2022-06-01': 70.0, '2022-07-01': 945.0, '2022-08-01': 996.0}, 
        ('Sweet', 'MED', 'W2'): {'2022-06-01': 70.0, '2022-07-01': 945.0, '2022-08-01': 1044.0},
        ('Sweet', 'MED', 'W3'): {'2022-06-01': 70.0, '2022-07-01': 1015.0, '2022-08-01': 1044.0}, 
        ('Sweet', 'MED', 'W4'): {'2022-06-01': 70.0, '2022-07-01': 1015.0, '2022-08-01': 1096.0}})
    .rename_axis(columns=['Category', 'Destination', 'Week'])
)

# stack the df to make it long, sum along columns, add column names and unstack back
df = df.stack().sum(axis=1).to_frame(name=('Sweet', 'NWE+MED')).unstack()
# output
df
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

First I get rid of the first 2 rows ('category' and 'destinations').

```
df = df.iloc[2:] # You can add them after if you wish
df_NWE_MED = pd.DataFrame() # Empty dataframe
df.columns = ['Week', 'W1_NWE', 'W2_NWE', 'W3_NWE', 'W4_NWE', 'W1_MED', 'W2_MED', 'W3_MED', 'W4_MED'] # This is just more for tidy up
```

Then i Sum up the columns skipping in steps of 4, also I convert the columns to float to be sure that is the correct format of your data frame:

```
for i in range(1, 5): #There are many ways to count here to be dynamic.
    df_NWE_MED[f'W{i}'] = df.iloc[:,i].astype(float) + df.iloc[:,i+4].astype(float)
```

Now we just need to concatenate with the weeks:

```
df_NWE_MED = pd.concat([df['Week'], df_NWE_MED], axis=1)
```

The output:

```
                   Week     W1      W2      W3      W4
2   2022-06-01 00:00:00 70.0    70.0    70.0    140.0
3   2022-07-01 00:00:00 1087.0  1087.0  1794.0  1794.0
4   2022-08-01 00:00:00 1232.0  1705.0  1776.0  2010.0
```